# Oracle debugging technique for row difference

Tags: oracle, oracle10g

I am running a query on production and it is say returning me 500 rows and I have the same copy on my dev and the query is returning only 497 rows.

What approach or steps can be taken to compare the results?

Is there a tool?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming there is a database link between the two databases and that the data being returned matches for most of the rows in question, you could use a MINUS operation.  Something like

```
SELECT list_of_columns
  FROM some_table
 WHERE some_criteria
MINUS
SELECT list_of_columns
  FROM some_table@db_link_to_dev
 WHERE some_criteria
```

will show you the rows that are returned by the first query that do not have an identical match in the rows returned from the second query.  Ideally, that would show you just the three extra rows.  But it may return additional rows if the data returned for some columns is different in the two environments.

Comment: Thanks so much! I don't have link between these databases is there any other technique that are normally used?

Comment: @kalls - Assuming you cannot get a database link created (which I'd really push for if you're doing this sort of analysis with any regularity), you could always unload the results of the production query to a flat file, load that into a new table in the development database, and then do a MINUS.  Obviously, that's a lot more work than simply having a database link available, but it can work in a pinch.

Comment: Thanks for flat file approach. I will keep you posted. Once again thanks.

Comment: I did export to excel file and then used access wizard to see the difference.

Answer (score 2):

If you can save the result sets in flat files, then you could also grab a copy of the free and open source [WinMerge utility](http://winmerge.org/) and compare the results. This eliminates the need to create any additional database objects. Plus, WinMerge is a valuable tool in it's own right.

EDIT: Assuming windows, of course. A *nix solution could be diff.

Comment: Yes, it is windows and have WinMerge I was thinking of excel files so didn't think of WinMerge. Thanks for this information.